# Merge Facebook applications into one

Tags: facebook, multiple-domains, facebook-apps

Facebook just announced support for multiple app domains (read the post [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/)) in their applications. We're having multiple applications since our website is localized, but now, with 
this new feature, we'd like all these applications to be merged into just one.

Is there any way to do this at this current moment?

Alternatively we'd have to ask all of our thousands of users to re-connect with Facebook once again just to get them all on just one single shared application.

Comment: hey, how will merging your apps help you? what are the benefits you are expecting?

Comment: The primary win will be that our users won't have to connect with every TLD that they're visiting. We have a lot of TLD's (and currently one FB app for each one), so if we could have just one app (which is now possible) it would be easier to maintain.

Comment: ok..so you want all your users, regardless of which app they use, to be authenticated from a central place? do your apps fulfill a single collective goal or they perform different functions? i'm curious :)

Comment: Exactly. It's one single collective goal - it's a platform for reviewing businesses which is available in nearly every country. :) As things are right now a user can't go from our .com site to .co.uk site and still be logged in, since it's two separate Facebook Apps.

Comment: Awesome, but now i think there is no other way other than @Igy 's solution. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, guess so too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this; you could slowly migrate users to the 'new' / 'primary' app - bearing in mind users will have to go through the auth dialog again